# Is it possible to use SharePoint's ValidateUpdateListItem endpoint to set a long string value into a field of type Note?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to work around SharePoint's behavior of setting list item metadata properties such as Editor and Modified when I update other list attribute fields.  I have a list containing Note fields, which I can successfully set via a MERGE call, even when the values of the Note fields are strings longer than 255 characters.  (This is as expected because a Note can be 63999 characters.)

But using MERGE causes Editor and Modified to be updated.  Instead, using a POST to the item's ValidateUpdateListItem method should update only the supplied fields, AFAIK.

The body of the ValidateUpdateListItem call looks like:

```
{:formValues [{"FieldName": "My_x0020_Internal_x0020_Field_x0020_Name",
               "FieldValue": "This is a string longer than 255 characters ...   really"}]}
```

But it fails when passing long strings to Note field values, with the error message in the result: "This field can have no more than 255 characters" and the error code 0x80131600.

Is there a way to pass a long string via ValidateUpdateListItem?

*n.b.* I'd be happy using MERGE and rewriting only the Editor and Modified fields via ValidateUpdateListItem, which wouldn't have the long string issue.  But it's not possble to reset the Editor to a user identity that is no longer in Active Directory, even if you set it to the Name value (e.g., `i:0#.f|membership|deleted@tenant.com`) that the Editor field had prior to the MERGE call.  In this case, SharePoint responds with a "We couldn't find an exact match" error, and leaves the Editor set to "SharePoint App," which loses the history we're trying to maintain in the document library.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is that even though the field is of type Note and long values can be written via MERGE, to write long values with ValidateUpdateListItem, the field must be created with `UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE"` in the field schema XML.

Thanks to [Michael Han](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/2680359/michaelhan-msft.html) on Microsoft Q&A.